# Copying an attachment to a new record on a table linked to a SharePoint list

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint

I am trying to copy a record to another record in the same table. The table is linked to a SharePoint list. I have tried using DAO, ADO, AppendChunk, SharePoint list GUID with an ADODB connection with no success. I have followed the following sites and, still, no success: [DAO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/data-access-objects/work-with-attachments-in-dao),
[Chunk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb220958(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN),
[ADODB](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3f739707-76f3-45ee-a952-f42a11e3cee0/copying-an-existing-attachment-data-type-to-a-new-record-in-access-2007?forum=accessdev).

When the code reaches the line **.MoveNext** the **.RecordCount** for the attachment field jumps to over 2,000. It seems to want to loop through the entire table and copy all of the attachments.

I created a temporary local test database to isolate where the problem is. I created 4 fields (ID [AutoNumber], FirstName [Short Text], LastName [Short Text], Document [Attachment]). I populated 3 records with data, copied the first record, and pasted it as a new record successfully. Then I sent that table to SharePoint and linked to it from Access. But copying and pasting won't work since you need to commit the record first and then deal with the attachments. My code is as follows.

```
Public Sub CopyAttachments(copyFrom As DAO.Recordset2, copyTo As DAO.Recordset2, fromAttachment As String, toAttachment As String)
    
    Dim objFromAttachment As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim objToAttachment As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim objFromField As DAO.Field2
    Dim strFullFileName As String
    Dim strSaveAs As String
    Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
    
    strSqlFrom = "SELECT Attachments FROM tblTest WHERE RequestID = '" & strRequestId & "';" 'From the calling function ---

    Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject

    Set objFromAttachment = copyFrom.Fields(fromAttachment).Value
    Set objToAttachment = copyTo.Fields(toAttachment).Value
    copyTo.Edit
    
    With objFromAttachment
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            .MoveFirst
            Do While Not .EOF
'                'Get file name to save as
                strSaveAs = GetAttachmentName(.Fields("FileName").Value)
'
'                Set the field to the file data
                Set objFromField = .Fields("FileData")

'                Delete file if it already exists
                If objFSO.fileExists(strSaveAs) Then
                    objFSO.DeleteFile strSaveAs
                End If
                objFromField.SaveToFile strSaveAs

'                Add a new child record
                objToAttachment.AddNew
'                Load the file as a new attachment
                objToAttachment.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile strSaveAs

'                Update child record
                objToAttachment.Update

                'Delete file
                objFSO.DeleteFile strSaveAs

''                Move to the next attachment
                .MoveNext 'Here is where the attachment count increases!!
            Loop
        End If
    End With

    copyTo.Update

    Set objFromAttachment = Nothing
    Set objToAttachment = Nothing
    
End Sub

Private Function GetAttachmentName(FileNameValue As String) As String

    Dim varTemp As Variant
    Dim strTemp As String
    
    varTemp = Split(FileNameValue, "/")
    strTemp = Environ("UserProfile") & "\" & varTemp(UBound(varTemp))
    GetAttachmentName = strTemp
    
End Function
```

Below is what I get from the test database.

```
When copying record 1 to record 6

https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/1/File One.pdf
https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/1/File Two.xlsm

When copying record 2 to record 6

https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/2/File Three.pdf
https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/1/File Two.xlsm
https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/2/File Three.pdf

When copying record 3 to record 6

https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/3/File Four.pdf
https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/1/File Two.xlsm
https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/2/File Three.pdf
https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/3/File Four.pdf

When copying record 4 to record 6

https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/4/File Five.pdf
https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/1/File Two.xlsm
https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/2/File Three.pdf
https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/3/File Four.pdf
https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/4/File Five.pdf
https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/4/File Six.pdf

When copying record 5 to record 6

https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/5/File Seven.pdf
https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/1/File Two.xlsm
https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/2/File Three.pdf
https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/3/File Four.pdf
https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/4/File Five.pdf
https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/4/File Six.pdf
https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/5/File Seven.pdf
https://sharepointsite.com/sites/TestSite/TestName/Lists/tblTest/Attachments/5/File Eight.xlsm
```

So my question is why does the attachment count increase to thousands when there is clearly only 1 attachment? Thank you for any help offered.

Comment: Have you step debugged? What is extent of copyfrom recordset? Is it filtered to a single record? Edit question to show SQL statement.

Comment: @June7 I have step debugged. The `copyFrom` recordset  returns only one record. When the `.MoveNext` line is executed the `objFromAttachment` recordset (which is the attachments) jumps to over 2,000.

Comment: Odd. Unfortunately, I do not use SharePoint. Show code that opens copyfrom and copyto recordsets.

Comment: Where is strRequestId declared and set? Also, strSqlFrom is not declared. This variable is not used, why is it in procedure? Do you have `Option Explicit` in module headers? I tested your code without SharePoint component and it works fine. Sorry, can't help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.

Direct transfer from attachment to attachment field is only possible if the source and destination tables are different. Direct transfer to the same table results in pointer issues and attempts to copy far more attachments than intended.

I created a local table with an ID and an attachment field. Then I simply call a function to transfer attachments from current to local, then from local to new, then delete from local.